# 3d analog to the Klein bottle

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

The Klein bottle is a non-orientable 2-manifold, which can be immersed in 3-space, but requires 4-space to be embedded.  A thick version ("glass") version of the Klein bottle is a 3-manifold with boundary, with the same properties.  Is there a non-orientable analog of the Klein bottle that is a non-orientable 3-manifold, which can be immersed in 4-space, but requires 5-space for embedding?  Does the "glass" version have the same properties?

Comment: The Cartesian product of a Klein bottle and an interval has all these properties (except possibly "requires $5$-space for embedding", hence the comment rather than an answer). The "glass version" (a tubular neighborhood of the zero section in the normal bundle defined by an immersion into $3$-space) is orientable (because $3$-space is orientable) and embeds in $4$-space (just "lift the neck slightly as it passes through itself" as for an ordinary Klein bottle).

Comment: Where did you learnt the "glass" version of K?

Comment: I have a glass Klein bottle (shown in my icon).  It is made of glass (pyrex, or similar).  If it were in 4d the tube could be lifted past the body wall, embedding it.  It is not a 2-manifold, but a 3-manifold because it is thick.  Thus I invented the term "glass" to express the concept of a slightly thickened n-manifold that is transparent.

Comment: This is bit off topic but perhaps interesting: the example from @AndrewD.Hwang has flat geometry $ E^3 $ while the answer from Lee Mosher has geometry $ S^2 \times E^1 $. Also neither example is $ \mathbb{R}P^3 \# \mathbb{R}P^3 $ (which is yet another manifold with $ S^2 \times E^1 $ geometry) so they do not generalize the fact that the Klein bottle is $ \mathbb{R}P^2 \# \mathbb{R}P^2 $.

Answer (score 3):

One can generalize the Klein bottle $K^2$, using its description as the quotient of $S^1 \times [0,1]$ identifying $(x,1) \sim (r(x),0)$ using an orientation reversing homeomorphism $r : S^1 \to S^1$. More generally, you could define $K^n$ to be the quotient of $S^{n-1} \times [0,1]$ identifying $(x,1) \sim (r(x),0)$ again using an orientation reversing homeomorphism. This has all the features that you ask for (with pretty much the same proofs), plus an additional feature you did not mention, namely that $K^n$ is a compact connected manifold.